# jquery new date() 12 hour format

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date that looks like this: `2015-09-06T21:10:00Z`

I use `new Date(2015-09-06T21:10:00Z)` and the date looks like this: `Sun Sep 06 2015 14:10:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`

That's good, however, I need to the time to be in 12 hour format.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so don't use `.toString()` and build your own...

Comment: You'll want a date library, like moment.js. If you have code now that isn't working, you should post the code and explain what you've tried.

Comment: I figured it out thank you for your comments